# Break MD5 hashed string exact format by knowing part of it

Tags: encryption, hash, md5

Is it possible to break/guess/detect format of MD5 hashed string when I know some parts of it (in my case one is login that can be changed, second is supplied in opentext along with the hash) and can change some of them and recalculate hash?

Length extension attack is not usable in this case because my data can be in the middle of hashed text.
Obviously bruteforce is also not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible.

The best you can do is bruteforce the missing parts.